# a question on projective limit of closure of locally convex spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(E_j)_{j\in J}$ be a family of locally convex spaces. Let $\widetilde{E_j}$ denote a completion of $E_j$ for each $j\in J$. If we consider the projective limit of the spaces $(E_j)_{j\in J}$ and of the spaces $(\widetilde{E_j})_{j\in J}$, then we know that $proj_{j\in J}\widetilde{E_j}$ is a completion for $proj_{j\in J}E_j$, that is, $\widetilde{proj_{j\in J}E_j}=proj_{j\in J}\widetilde{E_j}$.

Now, suppose that $(E_j)_{j\in J}$ is a family of complete locally convex spaces. Let $M_j\subset E_j$ be a subspace of $E_j$ for each $j\in J$ and let $\overline{M_j}$ be the closure of $M_j$ in $E_j$ for each $j\in J$.
Similar to above, if we consider the projective limit of the spaces $(M_j)_{j\in J}$ and of the spaces $(\overline{M_j})_{j\in J}$, is it true that $proj_{j\in J}\overline{M_j}=\overline{proj_{j\in J}M_j}$ ?  (where the right-hand side closure is taken in $\Pi_{j\in J}E_j$, endowed with the product topology, or equivalently, projective topology with respect to the projections $Pr_{k}:\Pi_{j\in J}E_j\longrightarrow E_k$.)

Can any body give a hint or/and a reference?

Comment: If $\widetilde{E_j}$ is a completion of $E_j$ I think there should be a metric. So are all $E_j$ normed ?

Comment: @Maksim No, the $E_j$'s are all (Hausdorff) complete locally convex spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume all the spaces are Hausdorff. Is it okay?

Then, the closure of a subspace inside a complete space should be the completion of that subspace. This is generally true for any uniform space. To see why, let $A$ be a uniform subspace of a complete Hausdorff space $X$, then $\overline{A}$ is a complete Hausdorff uniform space, so there uniquely exists a map from the completion $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ into $\overline{A}$ by the universal property. On the other hand, since the map from $A$ into the completion $\tilde{A}$ is uniformly continuous, it extends to a map from $\overline{A}$ into $\tilde{A}$. It is then easy to show that these maps are the inverses of each other.

So,

1. $\overline{M}_{j}$ is the completion of $M_{j}$, and
2. $\overline{\varprojlim_{j\in J}M_{j}}$ is the completion of $\varprojlim_{j\in J}M_{j}$.

So the desired conclusion follows.

I'm not very sure about the non-Hausdorff case, but I guess the conclusion is still true.

Comment: Yes, all the spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: @serenus Great. Is there anything unclear?

Comment: The first item is clear for me. But I still have dubt about the second item. Do you consider $\overline{\lim_{\longleftarrow j\in J} M_j}$ as a subspace of which space ?

Comment: @serenus $\prod_{j\in J}E_{j}$, as you wrote. The product of complete uniform spaces is complete.

Comment: @serenus More generally, the projective limit of complete spaces is complete.